# Passing different values to the same view - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg

How can I pass different values to the same view that's presented twice on the page?

Calling the views:

```
<div class="view1" ui-view="view1"></div>
<div class="view1 with-options" ui-view="view1"></div>
```

Inside the views:

```
<section class="views"
     ng-init="views.init()">

<div class="view"
     ng-repeat="view in views">

    <w-view data="view1"></w-view>

</div>
```

And w-view:

```
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     height="xx"
     width="xx">
    ...
</svg>
```

- One of the reasons is to have differ height/width values between the views.

Comment: At first glance, this requirement might be better modelled as a directive.  Then you can pass  attribute values to it.  Maybe separating the view template further would help.

Comment: Thanks Davin. For now, that's what I'm doing. But looking for a better way that can scale nicely and easy to maintain.

Comment: You can assign the same controller to each different view and it will store different values, per view... unlike a factory. Or you can assign a different controller to each view and the values will be different. But since you're essentially scaling an svg element, then a directive seems much cleaner. The svg could be in the directive's template and you could pass in the different width and heights as scope params

Comment: Hey Rob, "The svg could be in the directive's template and you could pass in the different width and heights as scope params" - can you give more info. on how to accomplish this?